# Suppress "Use of unassigned local variable" error?

Tags: c#

I have a method like so:

```
public static long? FromIpv4ToLong(this string ipAddress)
{
    var octets = ipAddress.Split(IpSplitChar);
    if (octets.Length != 4) return null;

    var success = long.TryParse(octets[0], out long a)
                    && long.TryParse(octets[1], out long b)
                    && long.TryParse(octets[2], out long c)
                    && long.TryParse(octets[3], out long d);

    if (!success) return null;

    return ((16777216L * a) + (65536L * b) + (256L * c) + d);
}
```

...now, the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` will never be "unassigned" by the point where they would be referenced, but the compiler doesn't see it that way.  Is there a way I can force the compiler to just "build it anyway"?  It seems silly to initialize these values ahead of time.

Comment: You should consider using `IPAddress.TryParse`, this will accept invalid IP4 addresses.

Comment: I work for an online ad exchange; we're processing 60-100K ip addresses a second, with a double-digit millisecond latency SLA.  `IPAddress.TryParse` adds noticeable latency, and is therefore verboten.  We can only use the simplest, fastest, most efficient algorithms for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just refactor the code to avoid the pointless local variable that's confusing things, taking advantage of the fact that within the `if` body, the compiler *does* know that everything is definitely assigned:

```
public static long? FromIpv4ToLong(this string ipAddress)
{
    var octets = ipAddress.Split(IpSplitChar);
    if (octets.Length != 4) return null;

    if (long.TryParse(octets[0], out long a)
        && long.TryParse(octets[1], out long b)
        && long.TryParse(octets[2], out long c)
        && long.TryParse(octets[3], out long d)
    {
        return (16777216L * a) + (65536L * b) + (256L * c) + d;
    } 

    return null;
}
```

Or using a conditional operator (and using shifting for simplicity):

```
public static long? FromIpv4ToLong(this string ipAddress)
{
    var octets = ipAddress.Split(IpSplitChar);
    return octets.Length == 4
        && long.TryParse(octets[0], out long a)
        && long.TryParse(octets[1], out long b)
        && long.TryParse(octets[2], out long c)
        && long.TryParse(octets[3], out long d)
        ? (a << 24) | (b << 16) + (c << 8) | d
        : null;
}
```

Comment: I think it's interesting that the compiler can figure this out, but not the other one.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: For your original code to work, them compiler would have to attach significance to the value of the `success` variable. There's a big difference between that and understanding code flow in terms of "if X and Y have both been executed, then any variables assigned in X and Y should be treated as definitely assigned".

Comment: Sometimes I get spoiled by what the compiler divines of my intentions, to the point it surprises me when it doesn't.

Comment: I find your first example more readable than your second example, hence preferable.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to ignore that compile time error, or any compile time error.  You *will* need to ensure that the compiler is capable of proving that no uninitialized local variable is ever read, you can't just tell it to "trust you".

Fortunately, restructuring the code such that the compiler can prove that no uninitialized variable is ever read isn't that hard:

```
public static long? FromIpv4ToLong(this string ipAddress)
{
    var octets = ipAddress.Split(' ');
    if (octets.Length != 4) return null;

    if (long.TryParse(octets[0], out long a)
                    && long.TryParse(octets[1], out long b)
                    && long.TryParse(octets[2], out long c)
                    && long.TryParse(octets[3], out long d))
    {
        return ((16777216L * a) + (65536L * b) + (256L * c) + d);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this instead:

```
public static long? FromIpv4ToLong(this string ipAddress)
{
   var octets = ipAddress.Split(IpSplitChar);
   if (octets.Length != 4) return null;

   if (long.TryParse(octets[0], out long a)
                && long.TryParse(octets[1], out long b)
                && long.TryParse(octets[2], out long c)
                && long.TryParse(octets[3], out long d)){
       return ((16777216L * a) + (65536L * b) + (256L * c) + d);
   }

   return null;
}
```

The compiler isn't smart enough to realise when success will be true.